# using condition on more than one pl sql blocks

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to use one condition on more than one pl sql blocks
instead of repeating some condition in all blocks ?
for example something like this :

```
BEGIN  
     select user_id from users  
     if :app_user_id = user_id  
         then do the bottom blocks  
     begin  
     end ;  
     begin  
     end ;  
     begin  
     end ;  
END ;
```

Comment: Maybe nested blocks? https://www.plsqltutorial.com/plsql-nested-block/

Comment: It would be helpful to have a bit more detail about what your blocks do - why you have separate blocks if the processing is related (which having one controlling condition suggests).

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of the question, you need to check a condition at different points in your code.

You could put that one condition in a procedure/function (depending upon your code) and execute the same rather than putting down those conditions again and again.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, why wouldn't it be?

I don't know how wise it is (what you accomplish with two consecutive execution blocks at the same level, which you couldn't accomplish in a single block instead), but possible it is. For example:

```
begin
  if 3 > 1 then
    begin
      dbms_output.put_line('First line');
    end;
    begin
      dbms_output.put_line('Second line');
    end;
  end if;
end;
/
```

Output (obviously, `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` first, if not already on):

```
First line
Second line


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```